# Atom Linter Not Work Said No Issue

Tags: atom-editor, lint

I'm new to Atom, and I installed Linter package.But it's not showing errors or highlighting code, Said "No Issue".

What I should do to get this to work?

My Config: `linter: {}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What packages do you have installed ? Just **linter** ? According to [the documentation](https://atom.io/packages/linter), Linter provides a *"top-level API to its consumer that allows them to visualize errors and other kind-of messages, easily."*

To my understanding, Linter is used to display the information provided by specific linters, so you also need to install those specific linters. 
For example, install **linter-jshint** or **linter-eslint** for javascript or **linter-htmlhint** for html...

Try for example installing the package "linter-jshint" and see if you get warning on an incorrect javascript file.

List of specific linters : http://atomlinter.github.io/